# fetch record in oracle in auto increment way from servlet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, servlets

I have a table named as abc in oracle and 4 records as follows:

```
       F         S        
      apple    mango 
      tiger    lion
      oak      banana
      pink     orange
```

I want to fetch these above records one after another when a user clicks on NEXT button like this:

home.jsp-----------------

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>
```

After clicking NEXT button 1st row (Apple and Mango) is fetched from servlet NewServlet.java:

NewServlet.java---------------

```
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from abc"); 

      if (rs.next()) {   // i have used if in stead of while                  
      rs.getString("F");
       rs.getString("S");
           }
request.setAttribute("fi", rs.getString("F"));   
request.setAttribute("fi1", rs.getString("S"));  
request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

result.jsp-----------

```
  String abc="", abc1=""
 abc= (String) request.getAttribute("fi");
  abc1= (String) request.getAttribute("fi1");
 out.println(abc);// displays Apple
  out.println(abc1);// displays Mango
```

Here I have added the NEXT button and when user clicks **NEXT** button next row that is **tiger and lion** ought to be fetched from database and to be displayed ,how it is possible????What type of modification should I do in sql statement in NewServlet.java?? or in the 2 jsp pages??

```
   <form action="NewServlet" method="post">   
   <input type="submit" value="NEXT">   
   </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I need the solution please......

Comment: You can use `LIMIT`, eg: `SELECT * FROM abc LIMIT 0, 2` and to get the next two `SELECT * FROM abc LIMIT 2,2`. Limit works like this `LIMIT offset, maxRecords`.

Comment: after clicking next button how servlet will recognize to fetch next record??

Comment: You can add a new `input` field to the form to keep track of the requests.

Comment: ya but how to add counter to track i am getting confused

Comment: I've misunderstood your problem, not I see that you've got 2 different `jsp` pages and you communicate info from one to the other using a `servlet`. In this situation you can use the database to keep track of the requests.

Comment: ya in both the jsp pages NEXT button is there and is there any necessity of 2nd servlet??

Comment: There is no need for a `NewServlet.java` you can do database operations directly in the `jsp` page.

Comment: ya but exception jasper...something like is coming while fetching record from oracle by database connection in jsp, hence i used servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

`home.jsp`

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="count"  value="first" style="display:none;">
   <input type="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>
```

`result.jsp`

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="count" value="second" style="display:none;">
   <input type="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>
```

`NewServlet.java`

```
String query;
if(request.getParameter("count").equals("first")){
     query = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY [someColumn] FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY"
}else{
     query = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY [someColumn] OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY" 
}
```

Like I said in the comments section, you can do database operation directly in the `jsp` pages and even if you couldn't this is a unusual way to achieve what you want.

My suggestion will be to have only one `jsp` page which retrieves the value from the database and use the offset based on a request parameter.

for example:

`single.jsp`

```
  <% 
     String count = request.getParameter("count");
     int c;
     if(count!= null && conut.match("\\d+")){
         c = Integer.parseInt(count);
         c++;
     }else{
         c = 0;
     }
     String query = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY [someColumn] OFFSET "+String.valueOf(c)+" ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY"
  %>
   <form action="single.jsp" method="post">   
     <input type="text" name="count"  value="<%=c%>"  style="display:none;">   
     <input type="submit" value="NEXT">   
   </form>
```

I haven't used `jsp` in a while, the syntax may be off.

Comment: hey it is showing d error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: I've just realized that Oracle databases don't have the `LIMIT` clause. What version of Oracle database are you using ?

Comment: @Tom I've edited my answer, now it will work on an Oracle database, you will have to replace `[someColumn]` with a column name from the `abc` table. Also to get a better understanding of how the query works take a look at this [article](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php).

Comment: thnx i am doing it just wait

Comment: hey i am getting an exception- java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset, after using while (rs.next());

Comment: @Tom that is because you are calling `rs.get.....` more then once, in your code you are calling `rs.getString("F")` and `rs.getString("S")` outside the `if(rs.next())` block.

Comment: hey that exception is not coming but i am viewing only first row

Comment: but it fetches the 2nd row only after 1st row but not the 3rd row and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70575/discussion-between-titus-and-tom).